# Loop through each slide and show a message box if a Tag found

Tags: vba, if-statement, powerpoint

I added Tags to slides and want to look through each slide and give a message box if the Tag is found.

The `If` works.

Having added an `Else`, the code is just returning the `Else`, even though the Tag exists.

```vb
Sub IfThenElse()
    Dim oSld As Slide

    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides

        If oSld.Tags("MYTAGNAME") = "341377444" Then
            MsgBox "Ref found"

        Else: MsgBox "not found"

        Exit For

        End If
    Next oSld

End Sub
```

Comment: If the tag doesn't match on the first slide, then your code calls `Exit for` after showing "not found"

Comment: ...you won't know if the tag wasn't found on any slide until after your loop has completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the loop to end after the first found tag or after the first slide w/o a tag, you'd need to mod this further. If you just want to get a msgbox for each slide where the tag is found, then this:

```
Sub IfThenElse()
    Dim oSld As Slide

    For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If oSld.Tags("MYTAGNAME") = "341377444" Then
            MsgBox "Ref found"
        Else
            MsgBox "not found"
        End If

    Next oSld

End Sub
```